# How to implement Cross Validation and Random Forest Classifier given feature sets as dictionaries?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, supervised-learning

I have got my `featuresets` as a dictionary containing elements in the form:

```
({0: 0.48447204968944096, 
  1: 0.035093167701863354, 
  2: 0.07453416149068323, 
  3: 0.046583850931677016, 
  4: 0.0, 
  5: 0.09316770186335403,
  ...
  162: 1, 
  163: 1.0}, 'male')
```

When I try implementing the `cross_val_score` or `cross_val_predict` from the sklearn library, it always results showing some error saying

> "float values cannot be dict".

Could someone please help me implementing the cross-validation using Linear SVC and Random-Forest classifier in Python?

I had tried this before:

```
train_set, test_set = featuresets[1:1628], featuresets[1630:3257]
np.asarray(train_set)
np.asarray(test_set)
clf = SVC(kernel='linear', C=5)
predicted = cross_val_predict(clf, train_set, test_set, cv=10)
metrics.accuracy_score(test_set, predicted)
```

Also, I am not getting how to implement the kfold cross-validation here.

Comment: convert your data to numpy arrays, thats all

Comment: The data you shown above is a tuple with two elements: first is dict and another is string. Is the string your target variable, that you want to predict. Also your usage of `cross_val_predict` is wrong.

Comment: What type is `featuresets`?

Comment: @Tonechas  'featuresets' is a simple python list whose each element is a tuple of the form I've mentioned in my question.

Comment: And what is `'male'`?

Comment: @VivekKumar yes, the string is what I want to predict. What's wrong in there? Could you please show me the implementation?

Comment: 'male' and 'female' is what I want to predict. Essentially, I am working on classification of gender on the basis of blog posts. As of this particular featureset of the training set, it belongs to 'male'; that's what it is. Others  contain 'female' label as well. @Tonechas

Comment: What values can yield the prediction? Only `'male'` and `'female'`?

Comment: @Tonechas Yes, only 'male' and 'female'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us first import the necessary modules:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
```

You have to create an instance of a random forest classifier like this:

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier()
```

Then you need to load `featuresets` (I don't have this data so I couldn't test my code) and convert your categorical variable into a numerical one, for example through a dictionary:

```
featuresets = # your code here
gender = {'male': 0, 'female': 1}
```

Next step consists in storing the features and labels as NumPy arrays:

```
X = np.asarray([[i[1] for i in sorted(d.items())] for d, _ in featuresets])
y = np.asarray([gender[s] for _, s in featuresets])
```

Now you are ready to estimate the accuracy of a random forest classifier on your dataset by splitting the data, fitting a model and computing the score 10 consecutive times (with different splits each time):

```
scores = cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=10)
print('Scores =', scores)
```

If you run the snippets above you should get a list of 10 scores printed.

Comment: What about Random Forest classifier? Would it work this way?

Comment: Yes, it is working. Thanks a lot for your time and effort :)